# Why does savefig and plot commands have to be in the same cell in an IPython notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to export some plots from a IPython notebook. Searching I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642528/how-to-export-figures-to-files-from-ipython-notebook) and could sort the issue. As it's noted in the answer, I had to call `savefig` in the same cell as the `plot` commands.

My question is, why do those calls must be in the same cell? My notebook server was started in `--pylab=inline` mode. If it's not inline the plot are exported just fine.

Comment: Don't use `--pylab` flag, it is deprecated. Use `%matplotlib` magic. Reason is to prevent memory leak we have to close the fig object in between cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are seeing the behavior from this [`part`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/86c4d270e87b2a8f63f19016b57f846ab6063d06/IPython/kernel/zmq/pylab/backend_inline.py#L18-38) of `IPython`'s code base:

```
def show(close=None):
    """Show all figures as SVG/PNG payloads sent to the IPython clients.
    Parameters
    ----------
    close : bool, optional
      If true, a ``plt.close('all')`` call is automatically issued after
      sending all the figures. If this is set, the figures will entirely
      removed from the internal list of figures.
    """
    if close is None:
        close = InlineBackend.instance().close_figures
    try:
        for figure_manager in Gcf.get_all_fig_managers():
            display(figure_manager.canvas.figure)
    finally:
        show._to_draw = []
        # only call close('all') if any to close
        # close triggers gc.collect, which can be slow
        if close and Gcf.get_all_fig_managers():
            matplotlib.pyplot.close('all')
```

After displaying the open figure all open plots are closed.

Comment: note that I'm not perfectly sure, so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because by default, the inline backend used in the IPython Notebook will close all matplotlib figures automatically after each cell is run. You can change this behavior via `IPython.display.set_matplotlib_close` as described [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.set_matplotlib_close).