# How do I export images of graphs to a pdf in Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I do not wish to export the entire notebook as a pdf - I've searched and found solutions for that problem. I want to only export the plots in my notebook to a pdf. Is there a Python library does allows for this?

Comment: Are you using matplotlib? You can save those figures as a pdf [directly](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html).

Comment: Thanks. I came across this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642528/how-to-export-figures-to-files-from-ipython-notebook

Comment: What I'm trying to do is export multiple graphs to one pdf. I suppose another option is to merge the pdfs?

Comment: Yeah I see. You can try to combine all charts in a single figure using `subplots`, but I understand that might get unwieldy. Another option is to save them all somewhere as .pngs, then use `pdflatex` to generate a nice report containing all the figures however you like. I don't know if there's a good way to do it in pure python/matplotlib.

Answer (score 2):

The [Jupyter nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html) command allows specifying a custom template.

[Michael Goerz](https://michaelgoerz.net/notes/custom-template-for-converting-jupyter-notebooks-to-latex.html) has written a full custom template for LaTeX/PDFs here:
https://gist.github.com/goerz/d5019bedacf5956bcf03ca8683dc5217

To only print the graphs, you could modify it to blank out any sections other than the output cells, like so:

```
% Tell the templating engine what output template we want to use.
((* extends 'article.tplx' *))

% Template will setup imports, etc. as normal unless we override these sections.

% Leave title blank
((* block title -*))
((*- endblock title *))

% Leave author blank
((* block author -*))
((* endblock author *))

% Etc.
((* block maketitle *))
((* endblock maketitle *))

% Don't show "input" prompt
((*- block in_prompt -*))
((*- endblock in_prompt -*))

% Hide input cells
((*- block input -*))
((*- endblock input -*))

% Don't show "output" prompt
((*- block output_prompt -*))
((*- endblock output_prompt -*))

% Let template render output cells as usual
```

To generate a LaTeX file, save the above as `custom_article.tplx` and run:

`jupyter nbconvert --to=latex --template=custom_article.tplx file.ipynb`

To generate the LaTeX file and PDF in a single command:

`jupyter nbconvert --to=pdf --template=custom_article.tplx file.ipynb`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most elegant answer, but it's also extremely flexible in case you want to do more than just put each plot on a page. You can use [`LaTeX`](https://www.latex-project.org/) to collect all graphs in a single pdf after exporting them as images. Here's an example where we save the graphs as `report/imgs/*.png`, then write a `report/report.tex` file and compile it with `pdflatex` into a final `report/report.pdf`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Create and save two images:

```
plt.bar(np.arange(5), np.arange(5)*2)
plt.savefig('report/imgs/fig1.png')
```

```
plt.bar(np.arange(6), np.arange(6)**2 - 1, color = 'g')
plt.savefig('report/imgs/fig2.png')
```

Write a `.tex` file to display both images:

```
img_data = ['fig1', 'fig2']

latex_src  = '\\documentclass{article}\n'
latex_src += '\\usepackage{graphicx}\n'
latex_src += '\\graphicspath{{./imgs/}}\n'
latex_src += '\\begin{document}\n'

for image in img_data:
    latex_src += '\t\\begin{figure}[h]\n'
    latex_src += f'\t\t\\includegraphics{{{image}}}\n'
    latex_src += '\t\\end{figure}\n'

latex_src += '\\end{document}'

with open('report/report.tex', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as handle:
    handle.write(latex_src)

print(latex_src)
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./imgs/}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \includegraphics{fig1}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \includegraphics{fig2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And finally compile:

```
!cd report && pdflatex report.tex
```

Comment: Drawing inspiration from your approach, a more elegant alternative might be to turn this into a custom LaTeX template for `jupyter nbconvert`.